# Lectura e iteración de archivos en Python

Tags: python, procesamiento-de-texto

Buen día, estoy iniciando en esto de Python y me encuentro queriendo leer un archivo y trabajar con él a manera de ejemplo.

El archivo viene así :

```
Day,ONE_DAY_PRECIPITATION

2020-06-01 0:00:00,1

2020-06-02 0:00:00,5.6

2020-06-03 0:00:00,4.1

2020-06-04 0:00:00,4
```

> Son aproximadamente 34 renglones.

El ejercicio propone los siguientes pasos:

1.- Eliminar todos los saltos de línea.

2.- Eliminar o saltar la primer línea que es el header.

3.- que el número que esta después de la "," se vuelva un flotante.

Este es mi código:

```
with open(archivo,"r") as rawData:  

    contador=0

    for linea in rawData:

        if contador==0:

            contador=contador+1; #este lo quiero usar para poder saltar la primer linea

        linea=linea.rstrip('\n') #este remueve el salto de linea

        dato=float(linea.split(",")[1])
```

La última línea divide cada línea en la iteración para quedarme con el dato y lo convierte a flotante pero genera error porque no logro saltar el header.

Ayer después de estar vagando por miles de foros para tratar de hacer funcionar llegue a los siguiente:

```
with open(archivo,"r") as rawData:  
    datos=[]
    i=0
    for linea in rawData:
        linea=linea.rstrip('\n')
        try:
            dato=float(linea.split(",")[1])
        except ValueError:
            pass;

        if dato!= None:
            datos[i]=datos.append(dato);
        
    print(datos)
```

cumple la función parcialmente ya que al hacer el print(datos) para ver la lista el primer valor que devuelve es "None"  además de que estoy seguro que hay una manera más elegante de resolver el salto de Header.

esto es lo que esta devolviendo:
[None, 1.0, 5.6, 4.1, 4.0, 6.2, 4.0, 3.4, 6.0, 7.8, 8.0, 9.0, 3.0, 5.9, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.9, 3.4, 2.1, 4.9, 2.3, 9.1, 5.3, 4.0, 6.0, 7.6, 9.9, 3.0, 2.2, 5.4, 0.8]

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: Lo escribió en una nota al interno del código

Comment: ¿qué salida debería producir el programa?

Comment: @abulafia debería producir una cadena con los datos flotantes que se encuentran después de la "," de cada línea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo tenías. En tu código compruebas si el `contador` vale 0 para incrementarlo, pero aún así no evitas leer esa primera línea. Podrías haber puesto el resto del código dentro de un `else:` para que sólo se ejecute si `contador` es distinto de cero.

Por otro lado, aunque extraes correctamente el dato, no haces nada con él. Supongo que querrás guardarlo en una lista. Es decir, algo como lo siguiente:

```
datos = []
with open(archivo,"r") as rawData:  
    contador=0
    for linea in rawData:
        if contador==0:
          contador=contador+1; #este lo quiero usar para poder saltar la primer linea
        else: 
          linea=linea.rstrip('\n') #este remueve el salto de linea
          dato=float(linea.split(",")[-1])
          datos.append(dato)
```

Cuando este bucle termine, la lista `datos` contendrá los números que buscabas.

#### Posibles mejoras

Hay otras dos formas de saltarse la primera línea. Una parte de la misma idea que tú has tenido, es decir, un contador de líneas. Pero no necesitas llevar tú la cuenta "manualmete". Puedes usar `enumerate()` sobre el fichero. Esta función puede usarse sobre cualquier objeto iterable (ficheros, listas, etc.) y te devolverá en cada iteración una pareja `indice, valor`. En este caso el índice será en qué línea del fichero estás (0, 1, 2, etc.) y el `valor` será la línea en cuestión.

Así pues bastaría con procesar los casos en que el contador de líneas sea distinto de cero:

```
datos = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as rawData:  
    for contador, linea in enumerate(rawData):
      if contador>0:
        linea=linea.rstrip('\n') #este remueve el salto de linea
        dato=float(linea.split(",")[-1])
        datos.append(dato)
```

Otra posibilidad es hacer uso del hecho de que el fichero (`rawData`) es un iterable, por lo que cada vez que hagas `next(rawData)` obtendrás una línea nueva, avanzando a la siguiente. En realidad eso es lo que hace `for` (va llamando a `next()` hasta que ya no hay más).

Podemos usar este hecho para saltar la primera línea, si haces `next(rawData)` nada más empezar. Después ya puedes hacer un `for` normal, que ya no encontrará la primera línea pues ya fue leida. Es decir:

```
datos = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as rawData:
    next(rawData)  # Leer y descartar primera linea
    for linea in rawData:  # Procesar las restantes
      linea=linea.rstrip('\n') #este remueve el salto de linea
      dato=float(linea.split(",")[-1])
      datos.append(dato)
```

Finalmente, si eres amigo del código ultracompacto y que ocupe el menor número de líneas posible (no siempre es lo más recomendable, la legibilidad es un punto importante, especialmente en Python), pues podrías hacer uso de una comprensión de listas a la vez que juntas en una sola expresión el `.rstrip()` y el `.split()`:

```
with open(archivo,"r") as rawData:  
    next(rawData)  # Leer y descartar primera linea
    datos = [float(linea.rstrip().split(",")[-1]) for linea in rawData]
```

Observa cómo de paso he omitido el `\n` que le pasabas a `.rstrip()` ya que esta función, si no recibe parámetros, eliminará del final de la cadena cualquier carácter "tipo espacio" (retorno de carro, avance de línea, espacio o tabulador) lo que es en general más útil.

Comment: Nota: no está del todo claro si las líneas en blanco que se muestran en el ejemplo de tu pregunta están realmente en el fichero o ha sido un problema de formato al pegarlo en StackOverflow. Si estuvieran en el fichero sería necesario saltárselas. Dime si es el caso para que edite la respuesta.

Comment: eres un crack!!! he entendido todo excepto el último pero por lo demás eres un genio ayer estuve cerca de 4 hrs sin lograr hacer el salto de línea y parece que lo has resuelto de una. Ahora para la pregunta de si están realmente en el fichero me parece que si ya que cada que aplico el str.rstrip() se nota como desaparecen y quedan ya una sobre la otra, no se si eso indiqué que son dos saltos de línea pero eres un genio de vdd! Ahora al final he ejecutado el primer código que fue lo más cercano a mi manera de pensamiento y la  lista queda genial. Como decimos en Mx eres un chingón(a)

Comment: Respecto a esto que dices que "quedan ya una sobre otra", no sé si te entendí bien, pero podría ser que el fichero original tenga al final de cada línea **dos** caracteres especiales, uno para línea nueva y otro para retorno de carro. Esto es típico si el fichero se originó en Windows. En ese caso el `.rstrip("\n")` estaría eliminando sólo el línea nueva, y dejando el retorno de carro. Es por tanto mejor usar `.rstrip()` sin parámetros que eliminaría ambos (así como espacios en blanco que pudiera haber al final de la línea)

Answer (score 0):

El contador que colocaste no resuelve el problema de no leer la primera línea porque solamente cuenta los ciclos, para saltar una línea puedes usar slicing `[1:]`. Otra cosa útil puede ser leer por líneas usando `readlines()`.

Te dejo un ejemplo práctico:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lineas=[l.rstrip('\n').split(',') for l in f.readlines() if l != '\n'][1:] # Elimina saltos de linea y primera linea
    datos=[[e[0],float(e[1])] for e in lineas] # Transorma numero en flotante
```

Devuelve:

```
[['2020-06-01 0:00:00', 1.0], ['2020-06-02 0:00:00', 5.6], ['2020-06-03 0:00:00', 4.1], ['2020-06-04 0:00:00', 4.0]]
```

Comment: antes que nada mil gracias por tomarte el tiempo. Ahora bien he querido ejecutar el código que me compartes sin mucha gloria jajaja igual al verlo me surgen algunas dudas. A la variable Lineas se le asigna el l.strip y .split sin embargo l nunca entiendo de donde sal y me confunde fuertemente l!= '\n'][1:] no termino de entender bien como es que esto ejecuta :(

Comment: La técnica que utilicé se llama list comprehension, no deberías haber tenido problemas para ejecutarlo, basta añadir un `print(datos)` para obtener el resultado que mostré.